# Remotely Managing Storage on Hyper-V 2012 Core

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-storage, remote-access

I have a core Hyper-V Server 2012 that I am remotely managing from a Windows 8 client. I can connect in Hyper-V Manager, Server Manager, and MMC. However, I don't understand how I can manage the physical hard drive (for ex, deleting vhdx files, creating folders, etc) from my Windows 8 client.

I tried to attach the remote share as follows:

```
q: \\MyServer\c$
```

It said command completed successfully, but I don't see the drive on my client's Explorer.

I can get to it in cmd.exe on the client but how can I manage it in a GUI?

```
explorer q:
```

Throws error:

[image]

Comment: Was Q mapped from cmd running as an admin or another user?

Comment: as administrator account and run as administrator. Posted exact error. (I can still "cd" to any directory on Q: via command line)

Comment: Also, if you can connect to the server manager, you should have the ability to connect to the Computer management. In this pane you can manage physical drives.

Answer (score 3):

Run `net use q: \\MyServer\c$` on your Windwos 8. Then check whether the drive Q is available in explorer. I have just checked on my WS 2012 R2 and it works.